# Isomorphism and Cardinality

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the group $(G, *)$, where $G =\{(x, y) \mid x,y \in \mathbb{R}\}$ isomorphic to $(\mathbb{C}, *)$, where $\mathbb{C}$ is the complex numbers.  My initial intuition says no since their are elements in $\mathbb{C}$ with orders that no element in $G$ has, but don't the two sets have the same cardinality and isn't that enough to establish an isomorphic map?

Comment: How is the operation $\ast$ defined on $G$?

Comment: They are both multiplicative and I meant C - {0} and (x, y) - {0, 0} to be my sets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Equal cardinality just means that there is a bijection. This bijection might ignore a lot if structure. For example,

1. $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$ have the same cardinality, are they isomorphic as fields?
2. $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb Q$ have the same cardinality, are they isomorphic as ordered sets?
3. $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Q$ have the same cardinality, are they isomorphic as ordered groups?

But this is not just true for infinite sets. For finite sets too!

4. Both $S_4$ and $\Bbb Z/24\Bbb Z$ have $24$ elements. Are they isomorphic as groups?

And the list continues ad infinitum. You already know the answer. You are just confused about the definition of cardinality (where the bijection doesn't have to preserve any structure).

Comment: Ahh you are right, thanks you for clearing up my confusion.

Comment: You're welcome. I liken cardinality to "shaking the set so hard, all structure falls off" and then you are just left with "a bag full of elements".

Answer (score 4):

Both groups having the same cardinality is a necessary condition (since isomorphisms are bijections), but certainly not sufficient.

Group isomorphisms must preserve the algebraic properties of the group (e.g. the order of each of its elements, as you say).